# dealing with string input in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to input string into fixed size char array.
I have a questions:

1. when I input a string which is bigger than the char array, the array become bigger without any additional declaration. I want to make the code only take the string that 'equal or smaller than the char array'.

Thank You.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

/***************************Function****************************/
int string_length(char s[]) {
    int c = 0;

    while (s[c] != '\0')
        c++;

    return c;
}
/**************************************************************/
char *str;
int arrSize;

void opt1()
{
    printf("Enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &arrSize);
    arrSize=arrSize+1;
    str = malloc(arrSize);
    return;
}

void opt2()
{
    printf("Enter characters: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    length = string_length(str);

    printf("your input is '%s'\n", str);
    printf("your input length is '%d'\n", length);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    int input = 0;

    while(input != 3) {
        printf("\n NAME \n");
        printf("\n");

        printf("--------------------------------------\n");
        printf("1) Making Array \n");
        printf("2) Check Array \n");
        printf("3) Quit\n");
        printf("\nEnter selection: ");
        scanf("%d", &input);

        if( input == 1 ) {
            /* */
            opt1();
        }
        else if(input == 2) {
            opt2();
        }


    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: 1) `scanf("%s\n", &str);` --> `scanf("%s", str);`

Comment: but my Xcode don't allow me it, I think "%s" doesn't match type with "char"

Comment: type of `str` is `char *`. (see `char *str;`). your actual code `char str;`, not `char *str;`.

Comment: so you mean I should change `char *str` to `char str` ?

Comment: you should not change.  I meant change `char str` to `char *str`

Comment: okay Thank you helping out firstly :) , `scanf("%s", str)` is not working in my code, do you know why ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93928/discussion-between-iambeast-and-bluepixy).

Comment: There is a need to look at the input and your actual code.

Comment: see [my TEST CODE](http://ideone.com/BsSsX0)

Comment: yeah I think the code is nice, `str = malloc(arrSize);` how is this can work? without 'sizeof'? and when I put more characters than array size it also take it. why is that?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always `1` in C. `n * 1` => `n`

Comment: _I put more characters than array size it also take it._  this is  undefined behavior. Possibly unintended destruction of the memory takes place. It may not discovered immediately if there even if the cause is discovered to segment fault immediately.

Comment: okay that weird, we malloc the array with fixed elements space, but it also takes bigger number of elements ... very weird...

Comment: you rewrite `scanf("%s", str)` by _second_

Comment: yeah I rewite it but, my question is how come the array become bigger if i put more characters than array size without any additional declaration.

Comment: use `realloc`. memory block that has been secured by `malloc` can be extended by `realloc`.

Answer (score 2):

OP wants to read data, yet if larger that the target array, then do not change the target array.

```
// 1: success
// -1 EOF
// 0: Input too long
int read_array(char *buffer, size_t size) {
  char tmp[size];
  size_t i = 0;
  int ch;

  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
    if (i < size) { 
      tmp[i++] = ch;
    }
  }

  if (ch == EOF && i == 0) return EOF;
  if (i >= size) return 0;  // too many
  memcpy(buffer, tmp, i);
  buffer[i] = '\0';
  return 1;
}
```

Normally code could use `fgets()`, but there are corner cases that fail to meet OP goals.

Comment: I am not sure how to use this function, so when i enter the string how it make it as a string variable and send to the 'read_array' ? use malloc?

Comment: @IAMBEAST Say `p` is your "fixed size char array"  and `L` is its size, then `int result = read_array(p, L);`.  Test `result` for `-1, 0,1` and the act per `EOF, too long an input, just right`

Comment: `memcpy(buffer, tmp, i);
  buf[i] = '\0';
  return 1;` it won't work, if you dont declare

Comment: @IAMBEAST Changed to `memcpy(buffer, tmp, i); buffer[i] = '\0';`

Answer (score 1):

To read in a whole line, you can use `fgets`:

```
char line[80];

if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) {
    // use the input
}
```

Now you won't need to check if the user entered more than the limit, since `fgets` will only get the first 79 (-1 for null terminator) characters; the remainder, if any, will be ignored.

Comment: The statement `the remainder, if any, will be ignored.` is not correct. fgets reads 78 characters and add a termination 0 character. It does not ignore remaining part of the line, which will be read in the next fgets, if any.

Comment: The -1 advice is not needed.  `fgets(line, 80, stdin)` is fine, `fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)` is even better.

Comment: but I want to make it as not accepting the input if it is bigger than size of array. so if the input is bigger it should not make an array, not taking the part of input.

Comment: You should use `80` rather than `79` , otherwise you are just wasting an allocated character